# Link a reportviewer report to an update form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer

I'm trying to figure out if what I want to do is even possible, or if I need to figure out another way to go. I have a reportviewer report that lists the service calls in our system, linking back to a SQL db through EF5. The primary key field is CallID.

What I'd like to do is set the report up so I can click on the CallID value for a given row and have it bring up my CallUpdate form (with the CallID value loaded into the form), rather than having to copy and paste the CallID from the report into the form.

I know I can set it to link to a URL, etc. Can this be done, or do I need to figure something else out?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to make the CallUpdate form a subreport within your main form and set its visibility based on a condition. Then pass parameters to this subreport. The parameter would be your CallID